# cherrypy: how to get all active sessions (storage_type = "file")

Tags: session, pickle, cherrypy

My aim is to track all logged user, in a website powered by cherrypy.
With sessions stored in RAM (`tools.sessions.storage_type = "ram"`), i can get the information through :

> cherrypy.session.cache.values()

But with sessions stored in a file (`tools.sessions.storage_type = "file"`), trying to do the same, i get:

> AttributeError: 'FileSession' object has no attribute 'cache'

How to access the information stored in the session files ?

**EDIT :**

The proposition of Andrew Kloos is to load the sessions files from the directory (given by tools.sessions.storage_path), and un-pickle the files. 
This works in most cases, but sometimes, one of the files is still LOCKED, and unpickling fails. 
On the other hand, I can not believe that there is a session **object** for the current session (namely cherrypy.session), and that there is no available object for the other sessions, and that one is obliged to go through the sessions files ...

Comment: I dug a bit and didn't see a way to access other sessions.  However even when there is a locked file there is a version of the same file that is not locked.  So just exclude lock files.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok looking at the cherrypy/lib/sessions file I see that getting the session values runs this load function...

```
def _load(self, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = self._get_file_path()
    try:
        f = open(path, "rb")
        try:
            return pickle.load(f)
        finally:
            f.close()
    except (IOError, EOFError):
        return None
```

So you just need to mimic that but also loop through all the sessions in the session file folder.  Try something like this...

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy._cpcompat import pickle
import os

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def asdf(self):
        # loop through all the files in the sessions folder
        for FileName in os.listdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname('sessions')) + '/sessions'):

            #  **EDIT**
            if(FileName.find('.lock') == -1)
                f = open(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname('sessions')) + '/sessions/' + FileName, "rb")
                sessiondata = pickle.load(f)
                print(sessiondata[0]['FirstName'])
            #  **EDIT**

        cherrypy.session['FirstName'] = 'adsdf'
        return 'hi'

cherrypy.config.update({
                    'tools.sessions.on' : True,
                    'tools.sessions.storage_type' : 'file',
                    'tools.sessions.storage_path' : 'sessions'
                    })

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: looking at the session file, i had indeed the feeling that they look somehow like pickle files !

Answer (score 0):

I'll just give you a simple one liner using python.

```
    sessions = os.listdir('./tmp/sessions')
    sessions = filter(lambda session: '.lock' not in session, sessions)
```

First, you list the session files in the directory.
Then, you filter out the lock files.

Comment: This is just assuming you store the sessions in a file at './tmp/sessions'